# Run a docker image built by Jib with multiple main class and choose which main class to execute at Runtime

Tags: java, docker, gradle, jib

I have a java gradle project with multiple main class, i want to build a docker image with Jib and chose which main class to run when i execute docker run.

Is it possible to do this with Jib or i have to build multiple docker image for each main class i have ?

If i dont choose a mainclass in jib gradle config, it failed with :

```
Multiple valid main classes were found: ...
```

I try with a custom entrypoint, but no success for now, but i dont no how to pass the MainClass as an argument

```
container {
   entrypoint = ['/bin/sh', '-c', 'java -cp $( cat /app/jib-classpath-file ) MainClass']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution quite simple with jib :

```
container {
    entrypoint = ['/bin/sh', '-c', 'java -cp $( cat /app/jib-classpath-file ) $MAINCLASS']
}
```

and

```
docker run -it -e MAINCLASS=HelloWorldJob image:1.0.0
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Container runtimes (e.g., Docker, Kubernetes, etc.) provide a way to override the entrypoint set in an image to whatever value you want. For example, with the Docker engine, you could do

```
$ docker run -it --entrypoint java image:1.0.0 -cp /app/resources:/app/classes:/app/libs/* example.HelloJarWorld
```

---

> If i dont choose a mainclass in jib gradle config, it failed with :
>
> ```
> Multiple valid main classes were found: ...
> ```

If you problem is the failure above due to multiple main classes, you can set [`container.mainClass`](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-gradle-plugin#container-closure) to your desired main class.

| Property | Type | Default | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| mainClass | String | Inferred** | The main class to launch your application from. The value can also be initialized lazily with a provider. |